# How to read value from property file using Java Script?

Tags: javascript, velocity

I added textfield and a button in velocity script that is used through a web app. When web app is launched start.properties file is read. There's a property: debug_on that can take two values 0 or 1.

So I want to display textfield and the button according to debug_on value. It can be done in velocity script via javascript, if I'm not mistaken (I'm not a pro in JavaScript), but I need to get the property value in order to move further.

How can I achieve it?

*UPDATED*

Velocity script example where main GWT (Java) code is embedded at the end:

```
<!--doctype head declaration-->

   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Web App</title>
      <style>
        <!-- styles -->
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/webapp.css" type="text/css"/>
      <meta name='gwt:module' content='$uri'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript" src="/$uri/com.myproject.gwt.main.nocache.js"></script>
        <!-- TextField and button are located here -->
        <table style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" class="gwt-DialogBox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
            <!-- some other part of a page tha will be persistent through all GWT pages -->
         </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java? The question is about JavaScript isn't it?

Comment: @Alderath Velocity is a Java template engine.

Comment: Could you be more specific like providing sample code?
I've never used `velocity script` so if you provide your input model or idea details more people might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the client and will not have access to any of the server's files.

You *can* use Velocity to set values within a JavaScript block and have a JS function use those values.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var startValue = '$debug.value';
</script>
```

Comment: Hm. I was planning to import javascript file in velocity script using <script language="javascript"> tag. This javascript file will also be located on server. For example in such structure: ROOT/velocity_scripts, ROOT/javascripts. But properties file is in tomcat's conf folder. I also have specific method in my Java code that returns the value of this property, but I don't know whether it is possible to call java methods from within velocity script file - I think one cannot.

Comment: If you can expose it to the web server you could grab the values through an AJAX call.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't fully understand the idea of getting a value through AJAX call. Could you please explain it in details?